# Load class with member variable from dll/so with pugg

Tags: c++

I've got two directories (eclipse projects in case is matters)

```
PuggMain/
├── OutputDataWrapper.h
└── PuggMain.cpp
```

with `OutputDataWrapper.h`

```
class OutputDataWrapper {
public:

    OutputDataWrapper();
    virtual ~OutputDataWrapper();
};
```

and `PuggMain.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Kernel.h>
#include <Animal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Loading plugins..." << endl;
  pugg::Kernel kernel;
  kernel.add_server(Animal::server_name(), Animal::version);

  kernel.load_plugin("libPuggSharedLib.so");

  vector<AnimalDriver*> drivers =kernel.get_all_drivers<AnimalDriver>(Animal::server_name());
  vector<Animal*> animals;
  for (vector<AnimalDriver*>::iterator iter = drivers.begin(); iter != drivers.end(); ++iter) {
    AnimalDriver& driver = *(*iter);
    animals.push_back(driver.create());
    cout << "loded plugin from kernel" << endl;
  }

  for(vector<Animal*>::iterator iter = animals.begin(); iter != animals.end(); ++iter) {
  Animal& animal = *(*iter);
    cout << "Animal kind = " << animal.kind() << endl;
    cout << "Can Animal Swim = " << animal.can_swim() << endl;
  }

  for(vector<Animal*>::iterator iter = animals.begin(); iter != animals.end(); ++iter) {
    delete *iter;
  }
}
```

and the other directory with the following files

```
PuggSharedLib/
├── Animal.h
├── Cat.h
├── Driver.h
├── Kernel.h
├── plugin.cpp
└── Plugin.h
```

The files `Driver.h`, `Kernel.h`, `Plugin.h` and `plugin.cpp` are taken straight from http://pugg.sourceforge.net/.

`Animal.h`:

```
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
  Animal() {}
  virtual ~Animal() {}

  virtual std::string kind() = 0;
  virtual bool can_swim() = 0;
  static const int version = 1;
  static const std::string server_name() {return "AnimalServer";}
};

class AnimalDriver : public pugg::Driver {
public:
  AnimalDriver(std::string name, int version) : pugg::Driver(Animal::server_name(),name,version) {}
  virtual Animal* create() = 0;
};
```

`Cat.h`:

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include "OutputDataWrapper.h"

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
  std::string kind() {return "Cat";}
  bool can_swim() { return false; }
private:
  OutputDataWrapper m_wrapper;
};

class CatDriver : public AnimalDriver {
public:
  CatDriver() : AnimalDriver("CatDriver", Cat::version) {}
  Animal* create() {return new Cat();}
};
```

The output from running PuggMain is:

```
Loading plugins...
dlopen: Success
```

which implies that the drivers vector doesn't contain anything. But when I remove the member variable m_wrapper from Cat, it works as expected:

```
Loading plugins...
loded plugin from kernel
Animal kind = Cat
Can Animal Swim = 0
```

It does work with other member variables likes int and string however.
My question is simply why? I'm clearly missing something most likely because  of a lack of understanding, but I'm not sure how to tackle this.

If you made is this far through the question, tanks already for reading. I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the declaration of the OutputDataWrapper() and  ~OutputDataWrapper() functions. Your plugin is dependent on these functions but cannot load them because they are defined in your main application.

If all the members of OutputDataWrapper are declared in the header the program works fine, otherwise it fails.

I think the following structure will better fit your needs:

```
PuggMain/
└── PuggMain.cpp

PuggMainLibrary/
├── OutputDataWrapper.h
└── Animal.h

PuggPlugin/
├── Cat.h
└── Plugin.cpp
```

Both the plugin and main application will depend on the PuggMainLibrary but will be independent of each other.

Comment: Deceleration? The functions are going slower than they were before?